# Access: Complex sum with count and union

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have to problem to sum two calculated values from different tables:

**Tables:**

- T_AACDB_Daily_Status (contains STATUS_ID, COMPLETION_DATE, DATE and APP_ID)
- T_AACDB_Service_Costs (contains SERVICE_COSTS_ID and COSTS)
- T_AACDB_Services (contains SERVICE_ID, DATE and QTY)

There is a Join on T_AACDB_Daily_Status.STATUS_ID = T_AACDB_Service_Costs.SERVICE_COSTS_ID = T_AACDB_Services.SERVICE_ID

**Calculations needed:**

- Count STATUS_ID from T_AACDB_Daily_Status As CountFromDailyStatus
- Multiply CountFromDailyStatus with Costs from T_AACDB_Service_Costs As SUM1
- Multiply Costs from T_AACDB_Service_Costs with T_AACDB_Services.QTY As SUM2
  and finally sum SUM2+SUM2

**Query:**

- The first query part counts a specific staus whithin a certain time period
- The second query part multiplies costs with the associated service_id

This is my Query so far:

```
SELECT 
      SUM(t1.[CountFromDailyStatus]* tC.[COSTS]) AS SUM1
FROM 
    (
    T_AACDB_Service_Costs AS tC LEFT JOIN 
          (
          SELECT 
          T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[APP_ID], 
          T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[COMPLETION_DATE], 
          T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID], 
           COUNT(T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID]) AS CountFromDailyStatus 
          FROM T_AACDB_Daily_Status 
          GROUP BY T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[APP_ID], T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[COMPLETION_DATE], T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID]
          )  AS t1 
          ON tC.[SERVICE_COSTS_ID]=t1.[STATUS_ID]
    ) 

LEFT JOIN T_AACDB_Services AS tS 
ON tC.[SERVICE_COSTS_ID]=tS.[SERVICE_ID]

WHERE 
    (NOT(t1.COMPLETION_DATE) Is Null)     
    AND (t1.[COMPLETION_DATE]>=DATEVALUE([Startdatum]))      
    AND (t1.[COMPLETION_DATE]<=DATEVALUE([Enddatum]))
    AND t1.[STATUS_ID]  = 'Code-Review'     
    AND NOT EXISTS          
        (
        SELECT *          
        FROM T_AACDB_Daily_Status t2         
        WHERE t1.[APP_ID] = t2.[APP_ID]          
        AND (Not(t2.COMPLETION_DATE) Is Null)            
        AND (t2.[COMPLETION_DATE]>=DATEVALUE([Startdatum])) 
        AND (t2.[COMPLETION_DATE]<=DATEVALUE([Enddatum]))          
        AND t2.[STATUS_ID] = 'Deployment'         
        );

UNION 
SELECT 
SUM(tC.[COSTS]*tS.[QTY]) AS SUM2
FROM T_AACDB_Services AS tS INNER JOIN T_AACDB_Service_Costs AS tC ON tC.[SERVICE_COSTS_ID]=tS.[SERVICE_ID]
WHERE 
          tS.[SERVICE_ID]="PSEUDO" AND (tS.[Date]>=DATEVALUE([Startdatum])) And (tS.[Date]<=DATEVALUE([Enddatum]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself:

```
SELECT 
SUM(Summe+gesamt2) AS gesamtTotal,
SUM(anzahlNeu+anzahlNeu2) AS anzahlTotal

FROM (
SELECT
    sum(t1.[AnzahlAusDailyStatus]* tC.[COSTS]) AS Summe, 
    sum(tC.[COSTS]*tS.[QTY]) AS gesamt2,
    COUNT(t1.[STATUS_ID]) AS anzahlNeu,
    SUM( tS.[QTY]+0)  AS anzahlNeu2

    FROM ((
           T_AACDB_Service_Costs tC 
             LEFT JOIN  (
                     SELECT 
                     T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[APP_ID] ,
                     T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID] ,
                     T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[COMPLETION_DATE] ,
                     COUNT(T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID]) AS AnzahlAusDailyStatus 
                     FROM T_AACDB_Daily_Status 
                     GROUP BY   
                     T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[APP_ID] , 
                     T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[STATUS_ID] ,
                      T_AACDB_Daily_Status.[COMPLETION_DATE]
                     )  AS t1 
          ON tC.[SERVICE_COSTS_ID]=t1.[STATUS_ID]
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN T_AACDB_Services tS ON tC.[SERVICE_COSTS_ID]= tS.[SERVICE_ID])

    WHERE 
    (NOT(t1.COMPLETION_DATE) Is Null)     
    AND (t1.[COMPLETION_DATE]>=DATEVALUE([Startdatum]))      
    AND (t1.[COMPLETION_DATE]<=DATEVALUE([Enddatum]))
    AND t1.[STATUS_ID]  = 'Code-Review'     
    AND NOT EXISTS          
        (
        SELECT *          
        FROM T_AACDB_Daily_Status t2         
        WHERE t1.[APP_ID] = t2.[APP_ID]          
        AND (Not(t2.COMPLETION_DATE) Is Null)            
        AND (t2.[COMPLETION_DATE]>=DATEVALUE([Startdatum])) 
        AND (t2.[COMPLETION_DATE]<=DATEVALUE([Enddatum]))          
        AND t2.[STATUS_ID] = 'Deployment'         
        )
    OR (((tS.SERVICE_ID)="PSEUDO-CR") AND ((tS.Date)>=DateValue([Startdatum]) And (tS.Date)    
    <=DateValue([Enddatum]))) 
)
;
```